# Wrong paths with TinyMCE Image Manager

Tags: php, html, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE's Image Manager 3.x.

The problem I am having is that when I insert an image the path is

```
../../../images/etc/myimage.jpg.
```

How can I config the image manager to not include

```
../../../
```

Please note I do not wish to strip the string.

Answer (score 0):

Put in the config:

```
tinyMCE.init ({
...
relative_urls:false,
...
});
```

Comment: This gives me the domain name also. I just want /images/etc/myimage.jpg

Comment: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:document_base_url
Does it helps you?